# Bootstrap Popover in loop not showing correct content

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

See image below, each item shows only the content from the first item, do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
$('body').popover({
    selector: '[data-popover]',
    trigger: 'click hover',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    delay: {show: 50, hide: 400},
    content: function() {
        return $(".popover-content").html();
    }
});

{% for activityItem in activity %}
<li>
    <div class="popover-container">
        <a class="popover-dw" href="{{ path('show_user', {'username': user.username }) }}"
           data-popover="true">
            {{ user.username }}
        </a>
        <div class="popover-content" style="display:none">
            <img src="{{ asset(user.avatar) }}" alt="{{ user.username }}"
                 width="80" height="80" style="float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0"/>
            <strong>
                {{ user.username }}
            </strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because you are using

```
return $(".popover-content").html();
```

which gets the html of the first element with class `.popover-content`

You need to get the `.popover-content` element relative to the element that triggered the event. The `content` callback will have the context of the anchor so you can just wrap it in a jQuery object and use `.next`:

```
content: function() {
    return $(this).next(".popover-content").html();
}
```

***[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wXxnC/1)***